# Unable to retrieve metrics for Registrations Created from Azure Notification Hub

Tags: c#, azure, azure-notificationhub

We have a requirement to retrieve some Metrics (registrations created and deleted) from Azure Notification Hub (Free tier) using the Notifications Hub REST API, after some research we found what metrics are available programmatically ([Metrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn458822.aspx)) and an example on how to call the API ([Programmatic Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn458823.aspx)). Currently we are able to get metric data for deleted and updated registrations but not for created registrations. We’ve tried deleting the device registrations from the hub and registering the devices again, we also tried using devices that haven’t been previously registered but we never get any records returned by the registrations created endpoint (registration.create).

Looking at the Monitor section of the notification hub on the classic portal we see the same behavior, data for registrations updated and deleted and no data what so ever for registrations created.

Is anyone else experiencing the same behavior?

Is there anything that we could be doing wrong that is not included in the documentation referenced above?

Comment: Could you let me know your namespace name? I work on the NH team, can look up what's going on in the logs and try to figure out what's going on there. Once it's done you can delete the namespace if you don't want to keep it exposed.

Comment: @NikitaG. The namespace for the hubs we have set up is Equiniti-PensionsIT-PNC. The pnc-systest hub is probably the hub with most registrations.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance the documentation has a typo. Could you try `registrations.create` (instead of `registration.create` -- plural registration**s** not single)?

Comment: I have tried both,  but when I try the plural version I don't even get a 200 response code. With the singular version I get data for both, updated and deleted, but for some reason for created I get a 200 response but no data regardless of how many times I try registering devices.